# How can Android 6 get the browser's history?

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

According to the 6 feature released by Android, READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions have been removed in more than 6 systems. So how can we get the browser's history?

Answer (score 0):

you should store them now internaly
see android official answer on the matter:

> This release removes support for global bookmarks. The
>   android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() and
>   android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() methods are now removed.
>   Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
>   permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level
>   23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use
>   the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks
>   data internally.